# Trying to create a custom background transition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm am very new to javascript so forgive me if this isn't really a problem.

So what I'm trying to do is when a user hovers over a certain instance of an object (I called it .taskbuttons), it should change background color from black to white with opacity 0.0, then 0.1, then 0.2, etc until 1.0 This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.taskbuttons').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)');
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
 });

 $('.taskbuttons').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
    $(this).css('color', 'white');
 });
});
```

I have previously tried the following to make it easier for myself, but it didn't work for some reason:

```
var x = 0.0;
while(x <= 1.0) {
 $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, x)');
 x = x + 0.1;
}
```

So now I ended up doing it as I showed above (the long way). However, The whole 10 lines happen instantaneously, so there's no effect seen. I was hoping to get advice here about how to delay between teh 10 lines to make the transition more visible. Or if there's a better way to do this, please let me know.

Again, I apologize if this is easy.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why it isnt working with your code, but this seems like something that CSS transitions are designed to do: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: use CSS transitions and skip the JS

Comment: So (Matthew Evans), are you saying that the syntax for the while loop should've worked properly? I was thinking that I maybe was supposed to use some qutoation marks or something.

Comment: `"x"` is portion of string  at `$(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, x)');` , not variable `x` .

Comment: ex: `.taskbuttons{background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);transition: 500ms background} .taskbuttons:hover{background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);` isn't that simpler?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use css transition to acheive this,rather than using javascript
Also bit confused with your requirement.You are looking for 
**user hovers over a certain instance of an object**  but in js you are using `mouseleave` which are contradictory. So assuming you want to change the opacity on `hover`,I have created this snippet.Hope this will be helpful

HTML

```
<button class="taskbuttons">
 I change color
</button>
```

CSS

```
.taskbuttons {

  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  background-color:black;
  color:#fff;
}

.taskbuttons:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:#000;

}
```

[WORKING COPY](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/t1eokqa1/)

You can use other css properties as required.

Answer (score 0):

Though I would recommend you to use CSS, I have updated you code. Now reasons why your code was not working:

- `$(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, x)');` here `x` is a string and not a variable. It should be something like `$(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, '+ x +')');`
- You are using loop, but loop will complete very fast and you will not see any transition. For this you should use `setInterval`.

#### Code

Note: *For demonstration purpose, I have toggled colors.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var interval = null;

  function updateStyle(self, color) {
    console.log(color)
    $(self).css('background-color', color);
  }
 
  function resetInterval(){
   clearInterval(interval)
    interval = null;
  }

  $('.taskbuttons').mouseenter(function() {
    if (interval == null) {
      var x = 0;
      var self = this;
      $(this).css("color","white")
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (++x > 10) {
          resetInterval();
          return;
        }
        updateStyle(self, 'rgba(0,0,0, ' + x/10 + ')');
      }, 50);
    }
  });

  $('.taskbuttons').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'White');
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
    resetInterval();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="taskbuttons">Button</button>
```